# Why would a time signal receiving watch have an airplane mode?

Tags: antenna, receiver

I've been looking at radio controlled watches online. I noticed that some radio controlled Casio watches have an 'airplane mode', which disables GPS and terrestrial time signal reception:

[image: Casio watch airplane mode]

Now, why would signal *reception* be restricted? The watch in question does *not* have a Bluetooth module or similar.

Comment: I see you have never flown international and had to argue about the legality of toothpaste. Or prove to a flight attendant that your smart watch isn't doing anything bad while switched off

Comment: Please enter an actual model number of a watch that has no bluetooth but has an airplane mode. When I searched, I found a variety of watches that have airplane mode, but they also have bluetooth.

Comment: @mkeith MRG-G1000B-1ADR

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most *useful* radio receiver designs utilize some form of the [superheterodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheterodyne_receiver) architecture, where one or more radio-frequency *local oscillator* signals are used to shift the frequency of the received signal to an *intermediate frequency* where it is more readily processed.

Typically, the local oscillator signal will radiate from a receiver to some degree - how much depends on the specific design, but it is not uncommonly detectable in near proximity.

Restrictions on radio frequency sources on passenger airlines have historically tended to err on the side of caution, restricting anything that could theoretically emit moreso than being specifically tailored to demonstrated concerns.  Since a local oscillator theoretically radiates, the argument was that you should not be operating one, which effectively meant that you should not be operating a radio receiver.

Of course digital processing circuitry typically radiates clocks and their harmonics, too...  But then, the shift in the last several of years towards services like in-flight WiFi also indicates a shift in thinking away from vague theoretical concerns.

Comment: This is the correct answer. For an example of how useful local oscillator emissions can be, this was the method used by Spycatcher Peter Wright and his team of MI5 boffins to search for KGB illegals listening in to Moscow in Cold War London. It is also, reputedly, the basis of the notorious TV detector vans in the UK.

Comment: Note that interference from receivers had actually contributed to [the deadliest airplane crash in history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster#Communication_misunderstandings) by masking the *stand by for takeoff* command with heterodyne whistle.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: According to the article, that crash was caused by interference from a simultaneous transmitter, not from a receiver.

Comment: @David It seems to blame "three-second-long whistling sound (or heterodyne)". Are heterodynes used in transmitters as well?

Comment: It's called "heterodyne interference" because the effect is the same: when two transmitters are simultaneously operating on the same channel, their carrier frequencies usually don't match precisely. So the difference between the two carriers turns into a loud audible tone that drowns out the intended signal.

Comment: Non-trivial transmitters typically also use heterodyne frequency conversion, yes, but the described incident however seems to not be about leakage from either, but rather about mixing.  Likely, with both transmitters in close proximity to the receiver, their signals are strong enough to put parts of the receiver circuitry into a non-linear regime where mixing between input signals would occur. In contrast, in the usual case with transmitters attenuated by distance, linearity means it is possible to hear two transmitters at once - such an ability to interrupt is allegedly why ATC stuck with AM.

Comment: This is also how radar detector detectors work in states like Virginia.

Answer (score 8):

I think that there is a very simple answer to this question that has nothing to do with electronics. A number of airlines prohibit the use of GPS receivers in flight. Their rationale does not actually matter. In order to comply with their rules, the watch must be able to turn off the GPS receiver somehow or it would be prohibited from being on the plane entirely.

Here is a list of airlines which do not allow GPS receivers:
http://gpsinformation.net/airgps/airgps.htm

Does GPS actually cause interference? Doubtful.
http://gpsinformation.net/airgps/gpsrfi.htm

If you wish to keep GPS enabled during flight, check with the pilot.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile phones, GPS receivers, laptops or indeed smart watches have no effect whatsoever on avionic equipment.  Most kit is designed and tested for restricted emissions and EMI tolerance in reverse.

The reason this equipment is banned has nothing to do with safety, but financial expedience.  There's a lot of electronic equipment in the world.  To rigorously prove my assertion in a way that would absolve an airline in a damages court case would take £100Ms.  No one wants to pay that, especially if it would have to be passed onto customers.  Better just ban the stuff.  People will still keep flying as they're a captive market. You'll fly naked sat in a transparent plane if necessary.

Try leaving your phone fully on the next time you fly a long way across Europe.  If you survive to land at the other end, you'll find perhaps 10 -15 messages on it welcoming you to various mobile networks that you over flew.  No problem.

Edit following comments:

There are approximately 1 million people flying in the air at any one time across the world.  If 1 in 1000 people randomly forget to switch off their e devices in flight (plausible), this theory is tested 1000 times/day across all randomly selected airliners in the world.  That's 365,000 times a year on every conceivable aircraft type.  That's a million hours /year of testing based on a 3hr mean flight time (plausible).  That's a pretty extensive systematic experiment. Nothing dangerous happens.

Comment: That irresponsible to advocate leaving said devices on.  The issue is there are a lot of planes in circulation that were designed way before wifi, personal gps etc.. really existed. I am thinking the 747 specifically here. They were designed to consider the DO160 at that time. Now chuck within the main structure another source of RF and well... There are clearly logged incidence where a radio transmitting device interfered with comms (didn't bring the plane down for sure but...). Newer planes have better shielding, routing, susceptibility limits.

Comment: @JonRB Which original bit of the 747 from 1970 do you think is still in service?  The multi functional computerised instruments or the GPS navigation system?

Comment: My "phone fully on" example occurs probably thousands of times a day with no significant effects - people forget to turn them off and there's a million people in the air at any one time.  If a phone had any tactical capability they would be immediately banned from all flights in the present climate.  They would be confiscated at security and you'd be arrested and waterboarded.

Comment: https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP756.PDF  "transmission levels produced by a portable telephone used near the flight deck or
avionics equipment bay exceeded demonstrated RF susceptibility levels for
equipment qualified to standards published prior to July 1984, and as such, as
equipment qualified to these standards is installed both in earlier certificated
aircraft and in newly built aircraft, the current policy for restricting the use of
portable telephones on all aircraft will need to remain in force; and".  I would trust the CAA over some random individual on the internet

Comment: New planes are a lot better but that doesn't dismiss the existence of older planes still in usage. At the end of the day the CAA/FAA/RTCA/EASA/ANAC/.../Airlines set the rules not the passengers. As long as they say "turn off during takeoff and landing" you run the risk of being removed if you do not adhere.

Comment: https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg16622401-000-danger-signals/

Comment: https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP%201066.pdf

Comment: @JonRB Yes, I admit that I'm a random individual who can't be blindly trusted.  However,    I've shown you numbers in my edit. Please show numbers to the contrary...

Comment: Thats not how this works. The CAA have show that levels above the qualification environment exist. They are the one that govern UK aerospace not you

Answer (score 0):

All radio receivers have circuitry that could emit RFI if not properly shielded. Better to be safe then try and determine the possible harm

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Can you expand your answer with some citations and references? One-line answers aren't very helpful.

Comment: This is true for all electronic devices, even if the receiver is disabled, or even if they don't even _have_ a receiver.